# Django CreateView not able to create model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am using Django CreateView on model object. The form gets rendered but on submitting Post button, nothing happens. In console I am receiving code 200 (Success) but object is not created. Also, I am using same HTML template and same code for Update View and it is working perfectly. Please help.

```
class EventCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    fields = ['name', 'event_attendees']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Model

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
location = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=EVENT_VENUES, default='sec-1, noida')
event_attendees = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', default='')
creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
form_rollout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('event-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Html template

```
{% extends "events/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Event</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', EventListView.as_view(), name='event-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserEventListView.as_view(), name='user-events'),
    path('event/<int:pk>/', EventDetailView.as_view(), name='event-detail'),
    path('event/new/', EventCreateView.as_view(), name='event-create'),
    path('event/<int:pk>/update/', EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='event-update'),
    path('event/<int:pk>/delete/', EventDeleteView.as_view(), name='event-delete')
]
```

Comment: i don't see any issue with this code. have you overridden any of the save methods(inside model or form) ?

Comment: I have not overridden any save method. As a matter of fact, the same code is working fine in one of my other apps.

Comment: Please show your urls.

Comment: Added URLs in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by overriding method form_invalid(). Apparently, the issue was in the implementation with FileField but was suppressed with the default implementation of form_invalid. On overriding the method, the actual issue arose.

Answer (score 0):

update code like this

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.creator = self.request.user
    obj.save()
```

try this

Comment: debug code with pdb and check... or wrap the code with try, except and print the exception if any.